# SwiftUI @FetchRequest does not update View until app restarts

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have 2 views in a ToDo app, one view allows the user to add new ToDos and mark them as completed and another shows a calendar that allows the user to see all the ToDos that they might have completed on any given day. A many to one relationship exists between the `ToDo` entity and the `DayOfYear` entity. When the user taps on the ToDo Complete button I update the `completedDay_` relationship under ToDo in Core Data. When I immediately switch to the calendar view `FetchRequest` doesn't contain anything even though I save the updated context immediately after updating the relationship. But when I restart the app, the calendar view shows the Completed Todo correctly.

```
do {
    let today = DayOfYear.withDate(convertStringToDate(day), context: context)
    todo.completedDay_ = today
    try self.context.save()
} catch {
    print("Error saving managed object context: \(error)")
}
```

**Extension DayOfYear**

```
extension DayOfYear {
    static func withDate(_ day: Date, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> DayOfYear {
        let request = fetchRequest(NSPredicate(format: "date = %@", day as CVarArg))
        let days = (try? context.fetch(request)) ?? []
        if let day = days.first {
            return day
        } else {
            let newDay = DayOfYear(context: context)
            newDay.date = day
            return newDay
        }
    }
 }
```

**Fetch Request in Calendar View**

```
@FetchRequest(entity: DayOfYear.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date <= %@", Date().startOfMonth() as CVarArg, Date() as CVarArg)) var daysOfYear: FetchedResults<DayOfYear>
```

**Sample Text View just to get a console print**

```
Text("Completed ToDos").font(.title)
    .onAppear {
        print(self.daysOfYear)
        // prints empty until I restart the app
    }
```

Isn't `FetchRequest` supposed to update itself and show the updated results from Core Data whenever it changes or does it not immediately update when relationships are updated in some way?

Comment: Short answer: no; longer - not always. In your case it seems Sample Text View body does not depend on `daysOfYear` directly (call in closure is not a dependency), so view is not updated.